# HTML input pattern only 1 space

Tags: html

I want a field which accept just letters and maximum one space. It is for a name. The name can be in two formats: "James" or "John James" (firstName or firstName lastName). Not case sensitive. The pattern i have right now allows an infinite of letters and spaces, but not white space as first character.

```
<input type="text" name="Name id="name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*" title="This field is required">
```

The pattern is taken from internet. I don't know why it has 2 brackets, why is a star at the end(guessing means 'infinite') and also why is the space character in the second bracket

Comment: Is this homework?
Look up regular expressions.

Comment: It is not homework. I still am and can't understand

Comment: also correct this, You have not closed the tag `name="Name"`

Comment: it's just a typo, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**1st one**
This 1st one you can only enter up to a maximum of two words because it will only allow only a single space

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+\s?[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

**2nd one**
This second one can allow as many words as you can but will only allow only a single space between each words

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*$"
```

Comment: How about this ? ^[a-zA-Z]+\s?[a-zA-Z]*$

Comment: does it mean that i can have any chars i want(atleast 1) 0 or 1 spaces and 0 or more chars?

Comment: @Ann Try this url. It will explain to you what your regex means http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=^[a-zA-Z]%2B\s%3F[a-zA-Z]%2B%24 any regex